# Set the Thread Group Loop count dynamically

Tags: jmeter

I have a folder where many files containing different SOAP requests. I want to run all of them. how ever this files count might vary when new requests are added and some are removed. So I want to set the loop count to the number of files in the folder. So that the user will not have to know the exact count. IS anyone has come across similar scenario and got a solution ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work it around with some scripting as:

1. Add a [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to your test plan
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell Sampler's "Script" area:

   ```
   File folder = new File("/path/to/your/folder");
   File [] files = folder.listFiles();
   int loops = files.length;        =
   vars.put("loops", String.valueOf(loops));
   ```
3. Add [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) after the Beanshell Sampler
4. Put `${loops}` into "Loop Count" input field

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on scripting in JMeter.